# how can I change WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer class to a main class

Tags: spring

how can I change a WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer class to a main class? the above mentioned class in spring mvc, now I want to convert it to spring boot. I created a spring boot project and created the packages and copied all of classes from spring mvc project to spring boot project I think I need to make some changes to WebAppInitializer class, but I do not know how to do that. the reason, when I try to  run it eclipse does not allow me to run as it java/spring boot application. I am stock with this for  a while. Thank you for your help.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    private Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

     private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVERLET_NAME="dispatcher";
     @Override
     public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {



         log.info("starting up");
         AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
         context.register(WebConfig.class);
          DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER_SERVERLET_NAME, dispatcherServlet);

       registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);

       registration.addMapping("/");
```

update:

the main class is on the top, all other packages are coming after that. these are my Annotation in my public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer { @EnableWebMvc, @Configuration, @ComponentScan(basePackages= "software.com"). Do I need to make any changes to WebConfig class?

Comment: Just remove it. Everything in there is done by Spring Boot already, you don't need that class anymore.

Comment: I deleted the that class it run as  java/spring Application, however. when I try to type localhost8080/projectname. I get this error:2020-05-18 13:40:53.054  WARN 10912 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /todo-list/items
2020-05-18 13:55:38.930  WARN 10912 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /todo-list/items
2020-05-18 13:55:39.721  WARN 10912 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /favicon.ico

Comment: Make sure that your class with the main is in a top-level class covering all other packages.

Comment: could not add a comment, so I posted on answer section.

Comment: You shouldn't add additional information as comments or as an answer, instead edit your question and add the information.